# NoSuchMethodError for JSONWriter.setDateFormatter after upgrade Struts from 2.3.7 to 2.3.33

Tags: java, json, ajax, maven, struts2

I upgraded Struts from 2.3.7 to 2.3.33 (using Maven). While with version 2.3.7 my web application was working without any issues, after the upgrade to 2.3.33, I receive the following exception when trying to access a web page that contains an Ajax call to the server.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.setDateFormatter(Ljava/lang/String;)V
> at
> org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:106)[struts2-json-plugin-2.3.33.jar:]
> at
> org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:203)[struts2-json-plugin-2.3.33.jar:]
> at
> org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:177)[struts2-json-plugin-2.3.33.jar:]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:372)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:276)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)[struts2-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:168)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
> at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)[xwork-core-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

The error occurs when my Java Action sends the json response back to the client.

**Below is the Ajax call I use:**

```js
  $.ajax({
        url :  "list-sample-json",
           //   data : options.data,
           //   dataType : "json",
    
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ sortParameters : sortParametersList, pageSize:options.data.pageSize, skip:options.data.skip }),
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (result) {
        options.success(result);
        },
        error : function (response, status, error) {
        openErrorDialog(response, status, error);
                                    }
    });
```

My action is accessed without any issues and returns `SUCCESS`. As mentioned above, the problem seems to occur when Struts generates the JSON response for the client. Below is also my Java class with `json` as a result type.

```
@Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = { "ignoreHierarchy", "false",
        "includeProperties", "textsampleList.*, count" })
@Injectable
public class ListSampleJsonAction {

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        
        List<SampleDTO> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        sampleList.add(new SampleDTO("sample")) ;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
          
}
```

I would like to mention that until 2.3.16.3 that the above implementation was working and I was getting a response (with the requested data) from the server.

I use maven 3.0.4 and Java 1.7_079. Can anybody suggest what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.setDateFormatter(Ljava/lang/String;)V`

The method is available at [javadoc](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-plugins/struts2-json-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/json/JSONWriter.html#setDateFormatter(java.lang.String)).

and from [Github](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/plugins/json/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/json/JSONWriter.java).

So you have as @HarKrishan mentioned in the comment a jar conflict version.

But if it's not then probably you need to have the correct version of [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) libraries on your classpath.

Comment: There is jar conflict

Comment: No conflict what?

Comment: The main cause of NoSuchMethodError is you might have compiled a class against a different version than what you are using at runtime. So there is jar conflict.

Comment: @HarKrishan I didn't compile anything (the plugin) is downloaded from the maven repository. if you compile from github then you won't get `NoSuchMethodError` because it explicitly shows that it has a method reference.

Comment: @RomanC I checked the asm library version and i use 3.3 which is the one included in xwork-core 2.3.33. I don't know if this is the right version. As for jar conflicts all my struts libraries are of the same version. I still have the same problem.

Comment: no i can't update Java. But i found the problem i had override JSONWriter in my project because something didn't work with the previous version. The overwritten JSONWriter didn't have the method setDateFormatter so I had to replace it. Thanks a lot for your comments, they really helped to find the problem.